# Siri INStartCallIntent works on iOS but not with CarPlay

Tags: ios, voip, siri, carplay

I implemented Siri and CarPlay. The INStartCallIntent works on iOS but not when initiating a voice command via CarPlay.

**Error** from I**NIntentDeliverer: Unable to find implementation of resolution method for facade slot name (null)**

From what I see, I implemented all methods declared on INStartCallIntentHandling but none is called.

Does someone know whats missing?

```
2023-08-29 11:34:52.551834+0200 MyApp[64559:4844776] [Intents] -[INIntentDeliverer _resolveIntentParameter:forIntent:intentHandler:updateIntent:withCompletion:]_block_invoke Unable to find implementation of resolution method for facade slot name (null) on intent <INStartCallIntent: 0x282a71830> {
```

PS:
Yes I got the required entitlements and can run the app on a real car AND the Car Play Simulator.